# Disable Primefaces p:sticky on mobile devices

Tags: jsf, primefaces, sticky

Dears I'm working on a responsive layout that has a sticky header that should be sticky only on desktop systems on mobile the sticky behavior should be disabled.

```
<h:panelGroup id="headerSection" class="SKBBackground" layout="block">
    header content
</h:panelGroup>
<p:sticky target="headerSection" />
```

PF 5.3.0
Theme - Modena
JSF - Mojarra 2.2.12
Glassfish - 4.1